# Max and min of a function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ on a set E

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set E=$\{x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2\le1, y\ge0\}$ and the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$
There isn't stationary points inside E : $\nabla f=0$ for $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ but the origin is a point of the boundary of E.

How  can i use lagrange multipliers method to study the boundary?

Comment: Why do you need Lagrange methods? It is immediate from the inequalities that $-1\le f(x,y,z)\le1$. Anyway Lagrange methods don't really help on the boundary.

Comment: but if I use lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the conditions of optimallity for the inequality constraints look at the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions.
Replace one inequality constraint with an equality constraint and you get a part of the boundary. Then we look at the conditions (here for maximizing $f$):
$$ x^2 + y^2 + x^2  = 1 , y \geq 0 \\
\Rightarrow \nabla f(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix}2x\\2y\\-2z\end{bmatrix} =\mu \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \lambda \begin{bmatrix}2 x\\2y\\2z\end{bmatrix}\\ \mu \geq 0, \ y \geq 0\\
 x^2+y^2+z^2=1,\ \mu (x^2+y^2+z^2) =0 $$
As we know $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ we get
$$\mu = 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}2x\\2y\\-2z\end{bmatrix} =\lambda \begin{bmatrix}2 x\\2y\\2z\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow 0=\begin{bmatrix}2 x (\lambda - 1) \\2y(\lambda -1)\\2z(\lambda +1)\end{bmatrix}
\\ y \geq 0,  x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
Now $\lambda$ has to be either -1 or 1, else the equations cannot be fulfilled. For $\lambda=1$ we get $z = 0, y = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \Rightarrow f(x,y,z) = 1$ and for $\lambda=-1$ we get $x =0, y =0, z = \pm 1 \Rightarrow f(x,y,z)= -1$,
thus the maximum on the first part of the half sphere is on $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ with value $1$.

You need to do this again for minimization (see in the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions that you need to change the sign in the equation for $\nabla f$) and for the other part of the boundary.